# Threadpool to Task Conversion

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, task-parallel-library, threadpool, .net-4.5

My current solution uses the ThreadPool to process transactions. Every couple minutes I grab 1-200 transactions and queue each one via the QueueUserWorkItem function. Something like this where 'trans' is my collection of transactions:

```
        For Each t As ManagerTransaction In trans
          Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(AddressOf ProcessManagerTransaction, t)
        Next
```

I want to switch it over to use the TPL, however, after much research I am still unsure of the best way to go about it.  I have the following options yet I haven't been able to find a general consensus on what the best practice is.

```
1) Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach(trans, AddressOf ProcessManagerTransaction)
```

Where "t" is an individual transaction in my "trans" collection

```
2) Task.Factory.StartNew(AddressOf ProcessManagerTransaction, t)
2a) Task.Factory.StartNew(Sub() ProcessManagerTransaction(t)
```

And this combination of the two:

```
3) Task.Factory.StartNew(Function() Parallel.ForEach(trans, AddressOf ProcessManagerTransaction))
```

Comment: There is no consensus, because all options can be useful, depending on what exactly do you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first option is generally perferrable because it does everything you want: parallelization and propagation of errors. Options 2 and 3 require additional means to propagate errors.

Option 2 might come into play if you *require* having tasks so you can compose them with other tasks.

I do not really see a case where I would use option 3.

Comment: Option 3 can be useful if you want to parallelize and also not block the current thread (e.g. when it's a GUI thread).